# Dynamic values for picklists depending on profiles

Tags: apex, picklist, profile, dynamic-visualforce

I am building a piece of functionality where I need to filter a picklist depending on the user profile that access the functionality. The behavior I want to build is the following: User with specific profile access a VF, the VF offers a picklist with **values depending on the profile**. If a different user access the will be offered a different set of picklist values.

The code I am using is fairly simple, the extension looks like this:

```
public List<String> productFamily {get;set;}
public String selectedFamily {get;set;}
...
productFamily = new List<String>();
Schema.DescribeFieldResult productCategoryDescription = SVMXC__Installed_Product__c.INS_G_Product_Category__c .getDescribe();

for (Schema.Picklistentry picklistEntry:productCategoryDescription.getPicklistValues()){

    productFamily.add(pickListEntry.getLabel());

}
```

The VF section looks like this:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:outputLabel value="Product Family"/>
    <apex:input id="productFamily" type="text" value="{!selectedFamily}"
                       list="{!productFamily}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

The different profiles have different visibility settings for the picklist values. However, when I access two different profiles, the picklist gets loaded with all the values contained in the field.

When I fetch the `DescribeFieldResult` I see I can use `isAccessible` to get access to the fields allowed by Profile, but I cannot access it by **values** in the field.

Is there any other approach to fill the picklist in the backend without using record types? (they are used for a different purpose). Is there any other API method that could help me fill those values?

Thank you

Comment: Basically this is what I am asking for: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000h1y6AAA I find the workarounds described in the comments WAY too complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only platform mechanism to vary which picklist values are shown is based on the record type. So if you can't use those because they are being used for a different variation, you will have to write your own code - the platform's meta data can't represent what you want.

That code probably needs to have two parts:

1. A way of defining the values to display for a particular profile. As you can't predict the profile names in use in the org your managed package is installed in, you probably will need to use a public custom setting to allow the profile names to be configured. For example, you could use a list custom setting where the name is the profile name and the values are a comma separated list of picklist values that you want displayed for that profile.
2. Some code that generates the picklist values for a particular profile. [UserInfo.getProfileId()](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm#apex_System_UserInfo_getProfileId) will give you the user's profile ID and you can then query the profile name and use that to lookup your custom setting values and display those.

Comment: Very smart solution. I buy it :)